# php Update filename from directory

Tags: php, forms, directory, rename

so the title is not full clear, my question , I'm using the code to rename the file from directory present in the server the problem is i have to use the HTML form and php to update the file name, i want to do this : there will be an option on every file for renaming it when i click on the option the box pops up and i have to type the new name for file and save it , any help will be appreciated. (before down voting think about the question.)

The code that I'm using to update the file name

```
<?php
include("configuration.php");
$target = $_POST['filename']; 
$newName = $_POST['newfilename'];
$actfoler = $_REQUEST['folder'];
$file = "files/users/";
$new ="files/users/";
$renameResult = rename($file, $new);
// Evaluate the value returned from the function if needed
if ($renameResult == true) {
    echo $file . " is now named " . $new;
} else {
     echo "Could not rename that file";
}
 header("Location:".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing these lines:

```
$file = "uploads/$loggedInUser->username$actfolder/$target";
$new ="uploads/$loggedInUser->username$actfolder/$newName";
```

To:

```
$file = "uploads/{$loggedInUser->username}{$actfolder}/{$target}";
$new ="uploads/{$loggedInUser->username}{$actfolder}/{$newName}";
```

To explain why:
You are using variables inside a string, which means you will want to tell PHP where the variable ends. Especially when referencing objects or arrays, but also when you are placing variables right next to each other. I'm guessing PHP evaluated your original line to `uploads/[Object]->usernamePizza/newname`

Comment: i think u haven't understood the question ; my renaming function is working but i want the rename option on every file and when i click on the option box popup with old name and then i will replace it with new name and save it.

Comment: oh then if you want the html file, you'll have to try to do something about it, and come back to us when you have really encountered a problem.

Comment: @Loïc i just want the option of rename on every file where i will click on the option and type new name for file and save it ,

Comment: This ***"i want to do this:..."*** should have been a dead giveaway. Which translates to (*reading between the lines*) ***"I want you to code this for me..."*** - Obviously, a loop is required to go over the entire folder and sniff out the files and add a rename function; **big job**. Ask the OP if he/she is ready to pay you an hourly rate. ;-)

Comment: i just want to know what should be the best way to do this not the entire code.

Comment: So basically, you want to use a for loop over an array and rename all. `foreach ($array as $value) { doFunkyRenameShizzle(); }`

Comment: yes i want to rename the file inside directory without typing the old name and newname ,,, just name name and save

Comment: Well, you'll have to have the original filename somewhere. Either as a hidden input, or as a key in your array. You can't tell the server just rename _unknown_ to newfile.html.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can call object properties in a string as you do.

try replace these lines :

```
$file = "uploads/".$loggedInUser->username."$actfolder/$target";
$new ="uploads/".$loggedInUser->username."$actfolder/$newName";
```

You may think about echoing `$file` and `$new` to confirm the path is nicely built.

On a side note, I'd recommend to really check the entries because this code can obviously lead to major security issues.